# SQL - Query within month difference from the first month, counting activity

Tags: sql, count, case

I have a table like below;

| user_id | status | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | frequent_user | 01.04.2020 |
| 1 | infrequent_user | 01.02.2020 |
| 2 | frequent_user | 01.06.2020 |
| 3 | frequent_user | 01.04.2020 |
| 3 | infrequent_user | 01.03.2020 |
| 3 | frequent_user | 01.06.2020 |
| 4 | frequent_user | 01.06.2020 |

The question is knowing how many new users converted to frequent_user at any point within 1m, 2m ,3m.
New user means f.e. user_id 1 has the first activity in 01.02.2020, so it is a new user there. and converted to frequent_user in 2 months. Another point is user_id 3 is a second-time frequent_user in 01.06.2020. But, it is not what I am interested in. I want to know the first time.

so output should be like that

| month | 1m | 2m | 3m | 4m |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01.02.2020 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 01.03.2020 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 01.06.2020 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I dont know how to write the query. Thank you so much in effort. Appreciate any insight.

Comment: Can you tag your RDBMS?

Comment: What happens to user_id 2 and 4? There is no record of when they converted from infrequent to frequent users. Do you automatically count those cases as conversion within 1 month?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a couple of CTEs to work slowly to the solution like below. I've provided the implementation in dbfiddle both in SQL Server and PostgreSQL.

```
WITH firstconversions AS (
     SELECT *, MIN(month) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY user_id) AS min_month,
               LEAD(status) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY month) AS next_status,
               LEAD(month) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY month) AS next_month,
               COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'infrequent_user' THEN status END) 
               OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY month) AS status_count
     FROM conversions
),
nextconversions AS (
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(month, month, next_month) AS duration,
          CASE WHEN status = 'infrequent_user' AND next_status = 'frequent_user' AND month = min_month AND status_count > 0 THEN 'Valid'
               WHEN status = 'frequent_user'AND next_status IS NULL AND month = min_month AND status_count = 0 THEN 'Valid'
               ELSE 'Invalid' END AS group_logic
FROM firstconversions
),
groupconversions AS (
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN group_logic = 'Valid' AND duration IS NOT NULL THEN CONCAT(duration, 'm')
            WHEN group_logic = 'Valid' AND duration IS NULL THEN CONCAT(1, 'm')
            END AS duration_flag
FROM nextconversions
),
grouped AS (
SELECT duration_flag, month
FROM groupconversions
WHERE duration_flag IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT month, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN duration_flag = '1m' THEN duration_flag END) AS [1m],
       COUNT(CASE WHEN duration_flag = '2m' THEN duration_flag END) AS [2m],
       COUNT(CASE WHEN duration_flag = '3m' THEN duration_flag END) AS [3m],
       COUNT(CASE WHEN duration_flag = '4m' THEN duration_flag END) AS [4m]
FROM grouped
GROUP BY month
ORDER BY month;
```

**SQL Server Solution:** See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a919e4d975182baa51c2bbe1b79d7daf)

**PostgreSQL Solution:** See [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=17489c35d910af77d78babc675c42e99)

**Results**

> ```
> month      | 1m | 2m | 3m | 4m
> :--------- | -: | -: | -: | -:
> 2020-02-01 |  0 |  1 |  0 |  0
> 2020-03-01 |  1 |  0 |  0 |  0
> 2020-06-01 |  2 |  0 |  0 |  0
> ```